# How to define a Make rule with the whole target being matched by the wildcard (%)?

Tags: makefile, wildcard, gnu-make

I know that I can use the following syntax to use pattern-matching in `make` rules:

```bash
%.csv : %.tsv
  tsv2csv $< $@
```

However, it seems this doesn't work, if the whole target should be matched:

While

```bash
%.csv : %.csv.gz
  zcat $< > $@
```

and

```bash
%.tsv : %.tsv.gz
  zcat $< > $@
```

work fine,

```bash
% : %.gz
  zcat $< > $@
```

doesn't.

I know that for this particular example I could use

```bash
%sv : %sv.gz
  zcat $< > $@
```

but just imagine I also want to use the same rule to get uncompressed copies of `*.txt` files.

Is there a reason why this isn't (and/or shouldn't be) possible and if not, how can I achieve that in (`GNU`) `make`?

I guess this is a common need (for examle to compile `foo.c` to `foo`) but I didn't find anything neither on SO, nor elsewhere (web search).

**Addendum**:

As pointed out in the comment/[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23337185/2451238) my minimal example above work just fine.

In my larger Makefile, however, it doesn't.

I figured out that this seems to be triggered by a second level of pattern-matching.

Consider the following Makefile:

```bash
all : testA testB

testA : testA.txt
  ln -s $< $@

testB : testB.txt
  ln -s $< $@

testA.txt : testA.txt.gz
  zcat $< > $@

testB.txt : testB.txt.gz
  zcat $< > $@
```

I created some dummy input files using

```sh
touch testA.txt testB.txt
gzip testA.txt testB.txt
```

If I run `make -n` I get

```sh
zcat testA.txt.gz > testA.txt
ln -s testA.txt testA
zcat testB.txt.gz > testB.txt
ln -s testB.txt testB
```

Using pattern rules, I can shorten the above Makefile to

```bash
all : testA testB

testA : testA.txt
  ln -s $< $@

testB : testB.txt
  ln -s $< $@

%.txt : %.txt.gz
  zcat $< > $@
```

Using `make -n` on this version, I still get the same output as before.

I now found out that I can also shorten it to

```bash
all : testA testB

testA : testA.txt
  ln -s $< $@

testB : testB.txt
  ln -s $< $@

% : %.gz
  zcat $< > $@
```

or

```bash
all : testA testB

% : %.txt
  ln -s $< $@

testA.txt : testA.txt.gz
  zcat $< > $@

testB.txt : testB.txt.gz
  zcat $< > $@
```

So the whole target matching the wildcard (`%`) was not the problem.

I cannot, however, combine the above simplifications in one Makefile:

```bash
all : testA testB

% : %.txt
  ln -s $< $@

% : %.gz
  zcat $< > $@
```

This Makefile results in the following output of `make -n`:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `testA', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

I thought that `make` might have a problem with two pattern rules having the wildcard as the whole target (even though I think it would be possible; at least in this case).

That's why I also tried the following version:

```bash
all : testA testB

% : %.txt
  ln -s $< $@

%.txt : %.txt.gz
  zcat $< > $@
```

To my surprise, this was accepted by `make`.

Unfortunately, I need something like this:

```bash
all : testA.csv testB.csv

testA.csv : testA.txt testA.tsv
  tsv2csv $^ $@

testB.csv : testB.txt testB.tsv
  tsv2csv $^ $@

testA.txt : testA.txt.gz
  zcat $< > $@

testB.txt : testB.txt.gz
  zcat $< > $@

testA.tsv : testA.tsv.gz
  zcat $< > $@

testB.tsv : testB.tsv.gz
  zcat $< > $@
```

I created test input using

```sh
touch testA.txt testB.txt testA.tsv testB.tsv
gzip testA.txt testB.txt testA.tsv testB.tsv
```

and running `make -n` returns

```sh
zcat testA.txt.gz > testA.txt
zcat testA.tsv.gz > testA.tsv
tsv2csv testA.txt testA.tsv testA.csv
zcat testB.txt.gz > testB.txt
zcat testB.tsv.gz > testB.tsv
tsv2csv testB.txt testB.tsv testB.csv
```

Taking the above observations together, I can shorten this to

```bash
all : testA.csv testB.csv

%.csv : %.txt %.tsv
  tsv2csv $^ $@

%.txt : %.txt.gz
  zcat $< > $@

%.tsv : %.tsv.gz
  zcat $< > $@
```

but not to this:

```bash
all : testA.csv testB.csv

%.csv : %.txt %.tsv
  tsv2csv $^ $@

% : %.gz
  zcat $< > $@
```

What is the reason for this behaviour of `make` and is there a way to change that?

Comment: What you want to do should work.  If it doesn't you should provide an actual example that doesn't work, including the makefile, the command you typed, and the results you got.

Comment: @MadScientist: Sorry for the bad example, I hope the new information are helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules with a target of `%` are treated differently by GNU make, as explained in http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Match_002dAnything-Rules

You might be able to get your rules to work with a smart placing of a double colon, perhaps on this rule:

```
% :: %.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are trying to execute the `make` command, but the following sequence of commands works for me.

Makefile:

```
% : %.gz
    zcat $< > $@
```

Commands:

```
touch foo.txt
gzip foo.txt   # Creates foo.txt.gz
make foo.txt   # Produces foo.txt again.
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer and sorry for not testing my MWE before posting it. I turned out it ended up too minimal to be working. Please see the new information to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @sg-lecram, The unusual thing is that the error message is: ` No rule to make target `testA.csv'`, rather than complaining about not being able to make the parts.

Comment: Regarding the error message, I think this is due to the way `make` treats pattern-based rules. AFAIK, the first rule than can be used is used. So  `make` scans the first rule and reasons that `testA.csv` could be made this way if there were the parts, or rules to make those. Since `make` seems to be unable to make the parts, this rule is simply ignored and `make` goes on looking for another rule matching `testA.csv` since there is also neither a file name `testA.csv.gz` nor a rule to make it, the second rule is also skipped. Since no rule is left, `make` concludes, there's none for `testA.csv`